# What is the best way in Java to get the drive that a file is located in?

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I've been looking for a way to get the drive a file is found in on windows (e.g C://, E://) but the best I can come up with is

```
.getAbsolutePath().getParent().getParent() etc.
```

What I want is just the first letter, e.g. **E:**.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Instead of using the bad, obsolete `File` class, why not use the [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) interface from `java.nio`?

Comment: Why are you interested in a *drive letter*? Tthere is only one operating system out there knowing of such but java programs should be written *operating system independent*. So what is the goal you want to achieve by determining the a drive letter?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle This application is specifically for windows, and with knowing the drive letter I'm hoping to be able to remove the drive using a third party application

Answer (score 5):

Use the path class since java 7, the getRoot() method doc is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getRoot())

> Returns the root component of this path as a Path object, or null if
> this path does not have a root component.

## Example:

```
String dllPathString = "C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\scilexer.dll";
Path dllPath = Paths.get(dllPathString);
Path driveLetter = dllPath.getRoot();
System.out.println("The dll is in: " + driveLetter);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for relative paths, and gives `null`. Instead, when there's a possibility that the provided path can be relative, use `path.toAbsolutePath().getRoot()`.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus you should make your own answer. Because that's is the most accurate way to finding the actual path of the file. In my case, my path is not begining with drive letter "C:\\...". Instead "\home\...". Because my production server is linux, while my local development is windows. Your comment given me the real actual path where is the file location.

Answer (score 0):

I've never see `.getRootPath()` so I can't tell you about it, but for type `java.io.File` you'll have `.getAbsolutePath()` which will return a String, and then you keep only the first or the 2 first characters

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,2)); // print C:
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath().substring(0,1)); // print C
```

Also using getRoot() :

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
Path path = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()).getRoot();
System.out.println(path); // print C:\
System.out.println(path.toString().substring(0, 1)); // print C
```

But as you said you need only the **letter** you jave to go by string and then keep the letter

Comment: My bad, I meant `.getAbsolutePath()` Thanks for your help!

Comment: This method seems a little fragile, but it works. I'd recommend `getRoot()` instead.

Comment: I can't call `.substring()` on `.getRootPath()`

Comment: @john you said you misunderstand with getAbsolutePath and now you're again talking of getRoot ^^, for getRoot it's : Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath()).getRoot()

Comment: It's not portable between platforms

Comment: @MarkJeronimus portable ? The OP asks for Windows. Also on Linux the root is `/` so no matter.

Comment: Hmm I expected `getRoot()` to return `/media/mark/B8D3-EDFA/` for a file on my USB stick, but it just returns `/` for this file too. So never mind. This requires more investigation to get working.

Answer (score -1):

`listRoots()` is static method of File, you can use this to find all directory of you computer.

```
File directories[]=File.listRoots();

for(File directory:directories)
    System.out.println(directory);
```

Your Required output :

C:\
D:\
E:\
F:\
H:\

**EDIT:**

You can use `canWirte()`method of file class that return true if and only if the file system actually contains a file denoted by this abstract pathname and         the application is allowed to write to the file; false otherwise.

In my case only return true only for 1st, 3rd and 4th case that is file directory.

Comment: This will give _all_ the roots, regardless of the file. You should explain how to use it to get _only_ the root that the file is in.

Comment: I have. I fail to see how `canWrite` will give you a single drive letter.

Comment: no it'll give all possible file directory otherwise for specific directory compare name from list.

Comment: The OP is asking how to find the drive letter that their file is in. Please show a full example that achieves this, because currently your answer doesn't make very much sense.

Comment: Your argument is wrong because there may be a file with the same path on a different filesystem and multiple (very! expensive! btw) checks will pass.